# Buttons to show or hide parts of web page

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to show/hide certain parts of a webpage by clicking on buttons. I thought I'd have to use javascript to do this until I saw the [gunicorn website](http://gunicorn.org). In it, they seem to be showing/hiding stuff just using html and css.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the mechanism it's using. What is making all the divs except the selected one hidden? Could anyone point me to an explanation of the process the gunicorn website uses? Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm not very experienced with HTML or CSS.
Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are also using Java Script.
I took this from the main.js

```
 // hook up tab links
    $(document).on('click', '.tabs ul li a', function(e) {
        activateTab($(this));
        //alert($(this));
    });
```

To my knowledge it is not possible to do it without Java Script

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, guess I'll have to learn some javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

In response to Raffael who is correct, it looks to be jQuery, not standard JavaScript. The same can be done either way. jQuery while at first glance looks cryptic does the same that JavaScript would in less lines of code, although it does require a framework.